# SQL Window function. Sum over date range

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

This must be a syntax error because I have found a number of solutions but cannot get it to work for my setup. I am using Aqua Data Studio with a Redshift connection.

I have transaction data and for each transaction I am trying to sum up previous transactions for a customer that meet a certain requirement and are within 15 days of the current transaction. This is what I got:

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_DATE, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RETURN_FLAG = '1' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANS_DATE ORDER BY TRANS_DATE RANGE BETWEEN ____ AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE
```

In the `____` spot I have tried the following:
`INTERVAL 15 PRECEDING`, `INTERVAL '15 DAYS' PRECEDING`, `15 PRECEDING`, `DATEDIFF(DAY, AUTH_DATE, -15) PRECEDING` and a few variations of these.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Redshift does not really support the `RANGE` window frame specification (well, except for `unbounded preceding and current row`).  Lobby Amazon.  Note:  If you want other approaches to solving this problem, ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are partitioning by TRANS_DATE and ordering by TRANS_DATE in your window function.  There will be only one value of TRANS_DATE per the partition so there is no ordering.  I think you have to rethink this (remove TRANS_DATE from the partition by?).